# Combobox.SelectedItem not working in parameter

Tags: c#, sql

Im retrieving data from a table on `Combobox_SelectionChanged`.
Whenever I try to add the parameter it no longer gets the data.
What's interesting is that if I replace the value '`Combobox.SelectedItem`' with 
a name `"Max"`, the data is retrieved. 
Also, if I specify '`Combobox.SelectedIndex == 1,2 or 3`' it still retrieves the data. 
What's wrong with `Combobox.SelectedItem` as value?

```
private void Combobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Combobox.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            string Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =";
            string dataFile = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            dataFile = "Database\\Data.accdb";

            string Selecte = "Select * FROM [Table] WHERE @1 IN([Name]) ORDER BY [Number] ASC";
            using (OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(Provider + dataFile))
            {

                if (myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    myConnection.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Selecte, myConnection);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { ParameterName = "@1", OleDbType = OleDbType.Char, Value = Combobox.SelectedItem });
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What type of object is bound to the combobox? I suggest you obtain the selected item and transform it's value into a variable (a string?) and use that variable in creating your parameter.

Comment: When you debug this, what does Combobox.SelectedIndex hold as the value?

Comment: @Crowcoder there are 3 strings in the combobox

Comment: @Crowcoder oh I found the issue... It seems the items the combobox was populated with had an extra letter in them compared to the items in the table. so it was a missmatch. That's why adding the value worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { ParameterName = "@1", OleDbType = OleDbType.Char, Value = Combobox.SelectedItem });
```

Changed To:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { ParameterName = "@1", OleDbType = OleDbType.**VarChar**, Value = Combobox.SelectedItem });
```